# Concurrency in C# and how to test it

Tags: c#, testing, concurrency, task, scheduling

I'm struggling create and test a situation like this one.

They system is distributed and has 3 actors:

- 2 clients
- 1 server

The flow of the operation:

1. Client #1 tells the server: "give me the whole list of orders!!"
2. The server starts sending the orders to Client #1, but this operation takes LOOOONG to complete.
3. In the meanwhile, the naughty Client #2 inserts a new order.

Result: Client #1 receives an OUTDATED list or orders without the newly added item by Client #2.

**First question:** how can I make Client #1 sync the list correctly without blocking new orders while a get operation is in progress. In few words: how to deal with this concurrency sync?

I have thought about something like an **initial sync**: the server retrieves the list in its currenty state and after it is received, it pushes all the possible new orders that may have been created (in the meanwhile).

**Second question:**
How can I make a test to reproduce this situation? Something like an interaction test to test the concurrency in this scenario. I have heard about custom TaskSchedulers, but I don't know how to make it work for this case.

Comment: For your first question, you are correct. Initial and incremental sync is pretty much the only (generic) way to solve this.

Comment: It's hard to give details without knowing what your storage is. If this is talking to a SQL database, you may well find that the database supports timestamped concurrency very simply with transactions.

Comment: I would like to implement it so that it doesn't rely heavily on any concrete storage technology. I have thought of something: Maybe the server could save the exact moment in which the request is done, and after retrieving the (outdated) list, it could push to Client #1 every single change that occurred after the initial sync.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

You have to consider, what should happen if Client#2 (or others) are heavily adding items so that the server is always busy resynchronizing. So you have to say somehow, the initial list, and now get the (read-locked) added (here could come some adds from Client#2 which you will miss).
As also suggested, if it is crucial for your clients to be *really* up-to-date, maybe an *Observer Pattern* with a *push* in addition to the *pull* would be fine. E.g. Client registers for added items and is notified about added items.

2)
Coyote may help you to write Tests to detect concurrency bugs https://microsoft.github.io/coyote/

I haven't tried it (yet).